# Viewing Final Score after Game End

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

Is there any way to view the final score given at the end of Game Dev Tycoon after the game's end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. It is only shown once you have reached the time duration of the game you set (such as 25 years,30 years,or 35 years). After that you'll never see it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can press ESC to open the main menu and then click on **High Score** to see all your previous scores.